# Assign variable value as a key to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
hand_1 = ['J', 'A']
one = dict()
for card in hand_1:
    if card == 'J' or card == 'Q' or card == 'K': 
        one.update(card=10)
```

I'm a python beginner. When I'm updating my dictionary I want to assign the value of a variable value as a key. What can I do? In the code above it will assign 'card' as key but I want the value of the card. How can I do this?

Comment: Do not use `.update`, simply do `one[card] = 10`

Comment: `one[card] = 10` will do it.

Comment: one[card] = 10?